# JPA tools will not connect to SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jpa

I am trying to connect to a database on my localhost machine from Eclipse using the JPA tools. I have been unable to achieve this so far. I want to create a JPA project and create the model from the tables that I have already created on the database. I do not seem to be able to get the connection string correct.

firstly I seem completely unable to create a SQL Server connection profile. Once I get to the second screen no options available that allow me to progress past it to completion. Found a thread on here that claimed this is a bug and I should use the generic driver instead. So this is what I tried.

[image]

I thought that the port number was 1433 and I have tried that but no change. I have also taken off the (localdb) part as the error message referenced it. Message remains the same.

**Error Message**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host (localdb), named instance mssqllocaldb failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: (localdb)". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:5247)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1871)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1608)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCConnectionFactory.java:53)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

I got the connection string from Visual studio as that is how I created the tables.

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=IdpValidate;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

I have checked the firewall on my machine but Eclipse is in there and I can connect no problems from Visual Studio so it can't be that (can it).

SQL Server Agent and SQL Server Browser are both on (again I can connect from elsewhere; mssms, vs, linqpad etc) Please help this is driving me mad!

I have also created a login and user (LetMeIn) but at the moment this is not making a diffrence as using my computer account can't connect through Eclsipe either.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have two sql servers installed on my machine and I was trying to connect to the wrong one. :(